# Can I burn a CD ISO to DVD?

Tags: dvd, iso-image, burning, compact-disc

So can I burn an CD ISO to DVD?  We've just got a bunch of DVD-R's lying around and I don't want to bother with torrents to download the new Fedora DVD.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the image is an ISO, most, if not all major commercial software can handle burning the image such as [Nero](http://www.nero.com/) or [imgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) on a PC  or [Toast](http://www.roxio.com/) or Disk Utitliy on a Mac.

As you are talking Fedora, you apparently can just Select DVD ISO image in file browser and  and do a right mouse click to open "with CD/DVD Creator", the set your write speed. Full steps are [here](http://sysdigg.blogspot.com/2008/05/how-to-burn-dvd-iso-image-in-fedora.html)

As to the specifics of the question of fitting a CD image onto a larger DVD disk. Yes it works no problem, you just waste the remaining space.

Answer (score 16):

**Short Answer : YES**

**Long Answer :** Technically isn't an iso image file burnable onto just about any type of optical media, even blu-ray? it just is kind of a waste, burning a cd image on a dvd

It shouldn't be that much different. But did you select a DVD project, or a CD project? They are different in Nero express. If you have started a DVD project, I don't think it should ask for a CD. I am not a pro with Nero, though :-) and fellow these steps

if you CAN use NERO. its the best you know.

```
open NERO BURNING ROM. (NOT NERO EXPRESS). 

click on ISO.

change nothing.

click on "OPEN"

select the ISO file, the file you want to burn to disc.
```

Or You any one of these buners http://iso.snoekonline.com/iso.htm

Comment: Burning an ISO to a DVD that will fit on a CD is not necessarily a waste: the same will drive will almost always read any DVD faster than any CD.

Comment: At this moment, I consider spending an hour to go buy a CD more waste, than using a €0,29 DVD instead of a €0,23 CD. ;-) But thanks for the technical info :-)

Answer (score 7):

As long as the medium is writeable and has enough space for the ISO it can be done. However practically it does not make much sense.

Windows 7 allows direct writing of ISO.
I personally use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/).

Comment: When you say "practically it does not make much sense", do you mean it doesn't make sense to waste so much space on a DVD?  If you don't have any CD-Rs lying around, it probably makes more sense to use a DVD instead of going out to buy a 50 pack of CD-Rs just to burn one CD-R.